# Named range to hide/show columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string that can take a couple of values (e.g. Madison, Chicago,...) and a couple of ranges named (Madison_Range, Chicago_Range,...)

Depending on the input of the user (more specifically, he drops an 'x' in a certain cell), the string takes on a certain value and I want the corresponding (hidden) range to be shown.

However,

```vb
Dim X as string
Dim Combination as string

x = Range("ACity:ZCity").Find("x").Name.Name
Combination= x & "_Range"

Range("Combination").EntireRow.Hidden
```

Does not do the trick, probably because vba looks for the named range "combination". Any ideas how to procede? I know that there is possibly a more elegant case, but this is a quick fix solution as part of a wide problem.

Comment: Try leaving out the quotation marks around Combination:
Range(Combination).EntireRow.Hidden
That way vba uses the string stored in that variable as you intended.

Comment: I still get hit with an error runtime 1004 "method Range of object _Global failed" unfortunately.

Comment: What are ACity and ZCity?

Comment: Two named cell ranges which between them form a column. The user will put an "x" somewhere in the column, and the name of that cell is extracted, "_range" is added and the  resulting named range should be made visible

Comment: Same point applies. `Range("ACity:ZCity")` will look for a range called "ACity:ZCity".

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim X As String
Dim target As Range

X = Range(Range("Acity"),Range("zcity")).Find("x").Name.Name
```

'this is potentially dodgy - you assume that the find will find an x - if it doesn't it will error. Also you need to refer to each name with a separate Range function to turn it into a cell reference and then an external range function to turn those two cell references into a full range.

```
Set target = Range(X & "_Range") 'point to the range
'to hide
'target.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
'to unhide

target.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification (and I realize this might not be the most ideal solution). Nevertheless, this code breaks on the "set target =" line with error: "Run-time error 1004: Method _Range of Object _Worksheet failed". Any suggestions?

Comment: what is X when it fails?

Comment: X works, it gets the exact necessary data to progress, in this case "Chicago" and there is a named range Chicago_Range present in the sheet, I triple-checked.

Comment: In the immediate window does ? range("Chicago_range").address  return the correct range? How about x="Chicago":debug.print range(x & "_range").address ?

Comment: Running that commando gives indeed the same error. Strange because, some lines above I literally define : Set Chicago_Range = Rows("20:50")

Comment: Ahh - There's a big difference between a named range - which is where you set the name of a range to be something, and creating a variable that points to a range. set Chicago_range = is setting a variable not a named range. You need Rows("20:50").Name = "Chicago_Range"